# how to solve data binding error with angular

Tags: angular, data-binding

when I call the variable `{{worksite.ref}}` 
for the first time, it shows the content of the variable 
but when I call it the second time it won't show anything

```
<div *ngFor="let worksite of worksiteList" >
<!-- ===================================== angular works fine here=================================== -->        
<span>{{worksite.ref}}</span> 
        <li id="li{{worksite.id}}" class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-1 visible-lg visible-md visible-sm visible-xs">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <a [hidden]="!isLocked(worksite.lockUser)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                        title="{{worksite.lockUser.name}} {{worksite.lockUser.firstName}}"
                                        onclick="$(this).tooltip('show')">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" style="color: #ff7900"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">

                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"
                                            [hidden]="!worksite.gpcindicator == 'CREER'"></i>
                        </div>


                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 visible-lg visible-md visible-sm visible-xs"
                style="cursor: pointer">
<!-- =================================== angular binding doesn't work here=============================->        
                <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{worksite.ref}}"
                    onclick="$(this).tooltip('show')" class="hidden-lg visible-md visible-sm visible-xs">
                 {{worksite.ref}}
                </span>
                <span class="hidden-xs  visible-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"
                    (click)="toggle(worksite.id)">{{worksite.ref}}</span>

                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
```

when I call the variable `{{worksite.ref}}` 
for the first time it shows the content of the variable 
but when I call it the second time it won't show anything

Comment: Best way to find root cause of this issue to to put in a "OnGetData(worksite)" anywhere you have worksite.ref.  Then in the code add a function OnGetData(worksite) and add a debugger statement.  What do you see when you do this?

Comment: is it possible to create a live demo base of your case ,  https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: You should be using optional chaining operator on the template. For example, instead of `{{worksite.ref}}`, use `{{worksite?.ref}}`. By doing so, you'll avoid things like "ref is not a property of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

it turns out it's a jQuery problem 
when i remove this

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{worksite.ref}}"
 onclick="$(this).tooltip('show')" class="hidden-lg visible-md visible-sm visible-xs">
</span>
```

every thing works fine,
now i have to find an alternative to replace jQuery in my angular project